# I want to apply an INNER JOIN and use WHERE condition using 3 tables

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  retailer 
WHERE 
  states = 1 
  AND newsletter.status = 1 
  AND (
    company_id IN (
      SELECT 
        id 
      FROM 
        retailer 
      WHERE 
        muli_ret_id = 0
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  email
```

Comment: I only see two tables. A 3 table inner join is like `SELECT .. FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.X=table2.Y INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.Z = table[12].P`

Comment: Could elaborate a bit?, maybe add a schema? We otherwise wont have any clue as to what your are trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your exact current query can be expressee using an inner join instead of the where clause.  You might try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.*
FROM retailer r1
INNER JOIN retailer r2
    ON r1.company_id = r2.id
WHERE 
    r1.states = 1 AND
    r1.newsletter.status = 1 AND 
    r2.muli_ret_id = 0
ORDER BY
    r1.email;
```

I use select distinct to remove possible duplicates which could arise from the self join.  But honestly, you current approach is fine, though I might use exists here:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM retailer r1
WHERE 
    r1.states = 1 AND
    r1.newsletter.status = 1 AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM retailer r2
            WHERE r2.id = r1.company_id AND r2.muli_ret_id = 0)
ORDER BY
    r1.email;
```